# SMO scripting entire database like Studio Management does with Generate Scripts

Tags: c#, sql-server, backup, smo

I am trying to set up a C# tool that scripts an entire database from the tables down to the stored procedures. I want to get all the schema and data. I am having a hard time finding much on the net on how to do this properly. I would think this would be common practice as an alternative if you don't wish to actually back the dabase up using Backup or Transfer, but I can't find much on the subject. Can anyone direct me to something on how to do this or tell me what needs to be done? I have found how to script Tables and stored procedures, but I want to get EVERYTHING in the database so that I can revert back to where it was if changes to the database breaks other things.

One of the reasons I am going about it this way is because i know that if you do a backup:

a.) it can get corrupt
b.) you can only do a back up on the server hosting the SQL server. You cannot back it up on your local machine if you are running the application remotely from the SQL Server. This is of course assuming that I cannot always rely on a UNC path or ftp script of any kind.

Comment: scripting out the data is a bad idea in general....it takes a LOT of space in your scripts to do this, much more than the actual data takes up in the database.

Comment: as I can appreciate your point, there is very good (well to my manager anyway) reason to do this. He wants a 1 click solution that will pull all of our data out and we can put it back in. and it has to be something that pulls it to where you are. So if my manager is on his desktop, it needs to be created there, so without shares and ftp and all that, backup / restore is out. again. i hear you, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at http://scriptdb.codeplex.com. 
This is a tool that scripts out a Database's ddl.

For Scrripting out the data you could try an approach like described here: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/ben_miller/archive/2007/10/18/scripting-tables-views-and-data-using-smo-part-3.aspx or try to use bcp, wich would be the better alternative for bigger databases.

Comment: Scriptdb seems to only be for 2000 and 2005. i'm on 2008R2. The other example link is only getting the table data, not getting stored procedures as well.

Comment: ScriptDb is Open Source Software. If you are able to build a c# app (and with a little effort you should be able, as there are no-cost SDKs for .NET) you can compile it against 2008R2 yourself.